# I want to know why I have to print the variable I'm working with in WordPress using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, wordpress

I am working on my plugin I make a call to a function trough ajax but It only retrieve information if I print the variable that I am working with

My Code

```
public function wpsgq_plugin_edit(){

    $wpdb = DB::getInstance();
    $wpsgq_settings = $_POST['wpsgq_settings'];
    echo $wpsgq_settings;  //<--- If I don't print this don´t work...
    $table_name = $this->prefix . 'plugin';

    if( $wpdb->update($table_name, $wpsgq_settings, array('id'=> $wpsgq_settings['id'] ) ) ){
        die("1");  
    }
    else{
        die("0");
    }

}

public function wpsgq_plugin_delete(){

    $wpdb = DB::getInstance();
    $wpsgq_settings = $_POST['wpsgq_settings'];
    echo $wpsgq_settings; //<--- If I don't print this don´t work...
    $table_name = $this->prefix . 'plugin';

    if( $wpdb->delete($table_name, array('id'=> $wpsgq_settings['id'] ) ) ){
        die("1");  
    }
    else{
        die("0");
    }

}
```

I wonder If exists a way to manage this variable without this `echo`  The two functions are called with `add_action('wp_ajax_` but what I really want It's to return the `die('value')` without `$wpsgq_settings` value

Comment: Why you're not using `global $wpdb`? What happens on your `getInstance()`? Also, passing `$_POST` data to the DB without `$wpdb->prepare()` is not a good practice.

Comment: Hi, I did made those changes too, but It doesn´t affect the result, because the ajax return 0 when I comment the line `echo $wpsgq_settings;` It's like ajax require this echo to see the variable. But I don´t know if I'm right... I added the `$wpdb->prepare` before pass the `$_POST` I didn´t know It was a bad practice thanks!

My `getInstance()` it is only to work with static function I needed to make a function to uninstall the plugin

Comment: I can't see what could be wrong only with the code you're showing... Can you create a [**minimal example** that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This way is possible to run the code and help you to debug it.

Comment: Hi, I made a little change and I used a separator with the data retrived from the server and then I worked with my variable in my dialog, It is not the answer but it have certainly solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

die throw a error, it doesn't echo or return any value. Ajax needs output hence why you echo a value or return the value. if this is missing it won't return anything (not that it dosent work).

If you want to create errors for yourself you can echo these instead of using die

```
if( $wpdb->delete($table_name, array('id'=> $wpsgq_settings['id'] ) ) ){
    echo "deleted table";  
}
else{
    echo "nothing deleted";
}
```

Comment: Hi David, maybe I did not cleared enough I certainly can change this in my code to `echo` a personal message, but I am working with ui-jquery-dialog so I am doing this with number code I think it is cleaner, but the doubt that I have It is why my code only works with the `echo $wpsgq_settings;`  If I comment the line It trigger the ajax and make everything fine but It don´t retrieve the response from the server

Comment: die it not returning any output, thats your problem, in your code above only echo $wpsgq_settings; produces any output. The function actually needs to output something for ajax to return it. you could echo yes, it will return that, etc.

Comment: Well maybe I am missunderstanding but certainly `die` return value I am working with this value right now, I already find a solution but I still have to `echo` the variable maybe as you said the ajax need it to return it